# CakePHP 3 how to redirect to requested page after re-logged in

Tags: redirect, cakephp-3.0

I need help to resolve a problem. I have an application developed in cakephp3. I am using Auth component. The app is working fine. The issue is when my app is idle for 30 min and session get expired and user click on some link then app is redirected to login page, which is normal.

But after logged in I want to redirect the user where he last clicked. Currenly its going to redirect default home page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add query string in your project URL like:
`http://awesomecakeapp.dev/?redirect=%2Fadmin%2Fadmins`

Then check for redirect query string in your controller and redirect accordingly:

```
if ($this->request->getQuery('redirect') != null) {
    $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect');
     return $this->redirect($redirect);
 }
```

The above will redirect to index action of admins controller in admin prefix. Same goes for others.

Hope this helps!